# Spark - Find the range of all year weeks between 2 weeks

Tags: scala, date, dataframe, apache-spark, hadoop

I need to find all the year weeks between the given weeks.

201824 is an example of an year week. It means 24th week of the year 2018.

Assuming that there are 52 weeks in a year, The year weeks of 2018 start with 201801 and end with 201852. After that, it continues with 201901.

I was able to find the range of all year weeks between 2 weeks if the start week and the end week are in the same year like below

```
val range = udf((i: Int, j: Int) => (i to j).toArray)
```

The above code works only works when the start week and end week are in the same year, for example 201912 - 201917

How do I make it work if the start week and the end week belongs to different years.

```
Example: 201849 - 201903

The above weeks should give the output as: 
201849,201850,201851,201852,201901,201902,201903
```

Answer (score 1):

Well there is still a lot of optimizations to do, but for the general direction you could use:
I am using `org.joda.time.format` here, but `java.time` should also fit.

```
 def rangeOfYearWeeks(weeksRange: String): Array[String] = {
  try {
    val left =  weeksRange.split("-")(0).trim
    val right = weeksRange.split("-")(1).trim

    val leftPattern  = s"${left.substring(0, 4)}-${left.substring(4)}"
    val rightPattern = s"${right.substring(0, 4)}-${right.substring(4)}"

    val fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-w")

    val leftDate  = fmt.parseDateTime(leftPattern)
    val rightDate = fmt.parseDateTime(rightPattern)
    //if (leftDate.isAfter(rightDate))
    val weeksBetween = Weeks.weeksBetween(leftDate, rightDate).getWeeks
    val dates = for (one <- 0 to weeksBetween) yield {
      leftDate.plusWeeks(one)
    }

    val result: Array[String] = dates.map(date => fmt.print(date)).map(_.replaceAll("-", "")).toArray
    result
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => Array.empty
  }
}
```

Example:

```
val dates = Seq("201849 - 201903", "201912 - 201917").toDF("col")

val weeks = udf((d: String) => rangeOfYearWeeks(d))

dates.select(weeks($"col")).show(false)

+-----------------------------------------------------+
|UDF(col)                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|[201849, 201850, 201851, 201852, 20181, 20192, 20193]|
|[201912, 201913, 201914, 201915, 201916, 201917]     |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with an UDF that uses the `java.time` API:

```
def weeksBetween = udf{ (startWk: Int, endWk: Int) =>
  import java.time.LocalDate
  import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
  import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

  def formatYW(yw: Int): String = {
    val pattern = "(\\d{4})(\\d+)".r
    s"$yw" match { case pattern(y, w) => s"$y-$w-1"}
  }

  val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-w-e")  // week-based year

  Try(
    Iterator.iterate(LocalDate.parse(formatYW(startWk), formatter))(_.plusWeeks(1)).
      takeWhile(_.isBefore(LocalDate.parse(formatYW(endWk), formatter))).
      map{ s =>
        val a = s.format(formatter).split("-")
        (a(0) + f"${a(1).toInt}%02d").toInt
      }.
      toList.tail
  ) match {
    case Success(ls) => ls
    case Failure(_) => List.empty[Int]  // return an empty list
  }
}
```

Testing the UDF:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, 201849, 201903), (2, 201908, 201916), (3, 201950, 201955)
).toDF("id", "start_wk", "end_wk")

df.withColumn("weeks_between", weeksBetween($"start_wk", $"end_wk")).show(false)
// +---+--------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
// |id |start_wk|end_wk|weeks_between                                           |
// +---+--------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
// |1  |201849  |201903|[201850, 201851, 201852, 201901, 201902]                |
// |2  |201908  |201916|[201909, 201910, 201911, 201912, 201913, 201914, 201915]|
// |3  |201950  |201955|[]                                                      |
// +---+--------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```